# Trying to learn F#...sort list of integers

Tags: python, sorting, f#

I've been using Python the past couple of months and now am trying to give F# a whirl.  Only...I don't really get it.  I've been reading documentation for the past few days and still don't completely understand how to accomplish basic tasks.

I've been following the tutorials on tryfsharp.org and fsharp.net.

For instance, how would I accomplish this basic task written in Python, in F# instead?

```
unsorted = [82, 9, 15, 8, 21, 33, 4, 89, 71, 7]
sorted = []
for n in range(1,len(unsorted)):
    lowest = 0
    for i in range(0,len(unsorted)-1):
        if unsorted[i] < unsorted[lowest]:
            lowest = i
    sorted.append(unsorted[lowest])
    del unsorted[lowest]
print sorted
```

Comment: "I've been using Python the past couple of months and now am trying to give F# a whirl...and still don't completely understand how to accomplish basic tasks." Don't worry, you feel like that for the first few weeks with F#, then it clicks and you can't imagine *not* using F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When porting code from an imperative language to a functional language, you should try to convert the algorithm that is used in the code, rather than the code itself IMHO.

The code is doing a [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) so you want to ask yourself, what does the selection sort do?

- find the minimum
- put it in the front of the sorted list.
- sort the rest of the items placing the results after the minimum.

So what would the code look like?  This would certainly work:

```ml
let rec selection_sort = function
    | [] -> []
    | l -> let min = List.min l in                         (* find the minimum *)
           let rest = List.filter (fun i -> i <> min) l in (* find the rest *)
           let sorted_rest = selection_sort rest in        (* sort the rest *)
           min :: sorted_rest                              (* put everything together *)
```

Comment: Wonderfully idiomatic. But what I really like with F#/Ocaml is that it lets you do it both ways, like this or like the version given by Yin Zhu.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that your python version is incorrect. It outputs:

```
[4, 8, 9, 15, 21, 33, 71, 82, 89]
```

Lacks `7`.

Here is a direct F# translation:

```
let unsorted = new ResizeArray<int> ([| 82; 9; 15; 8; 21; 33; 4; 89; 71; 7 |])
let sorted = new ResizeArray<int> ()
for n=1 to unsorted.Count-1 do
    let mutable lowest = 0
    for i=0 to unsorted.Count-1 do // i changed this line so the output is correct. 
        if unsorted.[i] < unsorted.[lowest] then
            lowest <- i
    sorted.Add(unsorted.[lowest])
    unsorted.RemoveAt(lowest)

printfn "%A" (sorted |> Seq.toArray)
```

The translated version is nearly exactly the same as the Python one. But this is not the ideal way to write F# programs. For sorting algorithms in F#, you can read a blog post on my blog:

http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/03/test.html

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this might not be exactly what your looking for if you want a direct translation, but F# and functional programming tend to emphasize declarative programming more than imperative languages. For example, if you want to sort a list of numbers, just sort them:

```
let unsorted = [2; 9; 15; 8; 21; 33; 4; 89; 71; 7]
let sorted = unsorted |> List.sort

//now print em out
sorted |> List.iter (printfn "%d")
```

If you're having trouble groking F#, it may be beneficial to read up on functional programming a bit to help you understand why F# does things differently. This article I wrote last year may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336127.aspx